# How to get data from webapp2.Request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, google-mirror-api

I am having trouble sending a string of bytes (an image) to my backend.

In my code I have:

```
#  sends a httplib2.Request
backend_resp, backend_content = self.mirror_service._http.request(
                                uri=backend_path, 
                                body=urllib.urlencode({"img":content}))
```

This sends a request where `content` is a large string of bytes.

in my backend I have:

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    image_bytes = self.request.get("img")
    logging.info(image_bytes) # output is empty string
```

Which logs an empty string.

I have also tried

```
image_bytes = self.request.body
```

and just setting `body = content` in the request, but these also return nothing

I know the backend is receiving the request because the backend logs have messages I have placed.

What is the correct way to send and retrieve my GET data?

**EDIT:**

Here's what `content` logs before trying to send it to my backend:

```
logging.info(str(type(content)))
# returns <type 'str'>

logging.info(content)
# logs a long string of bytes
```

On another note, I also get this warning in the logs when sending the request, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

I'm guessing that this warning means that the 1 positional argument it takes is `path=`, and it's ignoring my `body=` argument.  I think the warning changes to `(3 given)` if I add `method="POST"` or `method="GET"`

I tried using a POST method too, but `logging.info` won't display in my logs.  I tried just writing `self.request.body` or `self.request.get('img')` back to the response, and it still just returns an empty string like the GET method.

Comment: Probably a good idea to submit data with a post instead of a get.  I'm not sure how mirror_service works though..

Comment: I probably will use POST eventually, but the `logging.info` calls don't appear in my logs when I put them in the post method

Comment: mirror_service will need to do an http post not http get in order for you to see the post variables coming though in the post handler in webapp2

Comment: Tried changing to POST method, accessing the data with `self.request.body` and `self.request.get('img')` and writing it to the response, but it just returns an empty string.  My main concern is that `content` is never reaching the RequestHandler, or I'm accessing it wrong

Comment: By the way, I added another warning I get to the main question if that may hint at the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send a post from httplib2 :

```
import urllib
import httplib2

http = httplib2.Http()

url = '<your post url>'   
body = {'img': 'all your image bytes...'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))
```

[see httplib2 docs](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html#post-data)

To receive a post in [Webapp2](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html#post-data):

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    image_bytes = self.request.POST.get("img")
    logging.info(image_bytes) # output is empty string
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should give you and idea how it should be done.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It seems like the problem might be in my attempt to return `content` from the `Handler`.  I'm getting `302` responses in the log from the Handler, is that correct?  I'm writing the response like this: `self.response.out.write("Stuff here")`  I tried your code but with GET and the `self.request.GET` was empty

Comment: If you using a get, it's just self.request.get("yourvariable"). 302 is a redirect, are you redirecting?

Comment: I'm not explicitly redirecting anywhere.  `self.request.get("img")` was an empty string.  `str(self.request.GET)` also returns `UnicodeMultiDict([])` which makes me think something is going wrong in the sending of the data.  Is there a size limit that I might be passing?

Comment: Download fiddler and see what's getting passed down the wire. I've shown you how to use webapp2 with post handler. You should/need to do a POST to send image data as a string. There is a 10mb limit on appengine request size.

Comment: OK, I'll stick to POST then.  Will a `urllib2.urlopen(path,data)` work or should I stick to `httplib2.Http.request`?

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me, but it just wasn't working for some reason.  I rewrote the application in a new project and used a module instead of backend, and your code works fine.  Thanks for the help